# How to scroll to the last line of a multiline TextBox when it is not visible

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a multiline TextBox placed inside certain tab of a tab control.

When the tab containing the TextBox is not selected (so the TextBox is not visible), I append some text to it.

How can I make the TextBox to scroll automatically even when it is not visible?

All information I have found here is for TextBox that is visible and focusable.

Thanks

Comment: It would be nice to scroll the textbox of the changed tab when the tab changes. Selected events of the tab control are available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `EM_LINESCROLL` message

```cs
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr SendMessage(
    IntPtr hWnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

const int EM_LINESCROLL = 0x00B6;
```

```cs
var successful = SendMessage(textBox.Handle, EM_LINESCROLL, IntPtr.Zero, (IntPtr)1000000) != IntPtr.Zero;
```

You can also use the `SetScrollInfo` function, which seems to do the same thing.